# How to fix nvchad not displaying icons

Tags: neovim

I installed neovim from github , i specifically have the 0.7 version ,and then i clonned the nvchad repository https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad in ~/.config/nvim as stated in the installation tutorial , after that I used this comand:

> nvim -c "autocmd User PackerComplete quitall" -c "PackerSync"

which seemed to install the required packages
and then i typed nvim into my terminal and this was the result [image]
have i done something wrong? or should i do something else?
thanks in advance for your time

Comment: It looks like that you don't have a font which can display your icons correctly. You need to install them as well! I suppose that you're using a linux distribution. Just google which package you need and install it!

Comment: I had also similar issues and resolved those issues by following the post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78010819/10217732. In my case, I was missing to add fonts in my terminal.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because the font you are using doesn't provide those icons.
Find Nerd-Fonts patched version of your favorite font, install it, and **set it as your *terminal* font**.
https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads

Comment: Thanks. I had Fira Code, and thought it was enough. I apparently needed FiraCodeNerdFont.

Comment: I used nvchad on Ubuntu 20 on WSL and this does not solve.

Comment: @curiouscheese This problem has nothing to do with NvChad, Ubuntu, or WSL. It's bound to the terminal emulator you are using and which font it is configured to use.

Comment: `JetBrainsMonoNL Nerd Font Mono Regular` did the job for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @WieeRd you are right. I have change the Windows terminal font and it worked now!

Answer (score 22):

Besides installing Nerd fonts, you will likely have to change the font in the terminal settings.

In case you use Iterm. Go to the Iterm settings -> Profiles -> Text. Here you can find Font select, choose "Hack Nerd Font".

[image: Iterm2 settings, choose font]

Comment: you're a lifesaver. I wouldn't have guessed those steps for iterm otherwise. thanks!

Comment: also, nerd fonts do not work equally well. for example, i was using inconsolata-go-nerd-ont, which is missing some icons. hack-nerd-font works well, so if you're having issues as I was, maybe just use 'hack' for now and keep moving. best wishes, community

Comment: Nice! It works fine, but you have to install `font-hack-nerd-font` from `homebrew/cask-fonts`. Check this [ref here](https://www.geekbits.io/how-to-install-nerd-fonts-on-mac/)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue and finally, I resolved it by installing the  Symbols Nerd font.

1. Download the font from here [Symbols Nerd font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.0.2/NerdFontsSymbolsOnly.zip)
2. Extract it and install click on the .ttf file to install it.
3. Restart your terminal once and select any JetBrains fonts in the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need NerdFonts - patched fonts that can display glyphs.

Download them from [this link](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same issue after installing the Nerd fonts, go to your terminal preference and change to a custom font.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading 2 fonts

1. [Symbols Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.1.1/NerdFontsSymbolsOnly.zip) [ This is for symbols support ]
2. [Hack Nerd Font](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.1.1/Hack.zip)    [ This is a nerd font ]