# Neovim: icons missing nvim-tree-web-devicons

Tags: lua, editor, neovim

I added `nvim-devicons` and installed one of the patched fonts:

https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads.

the icons still not showing,

[image]

Config with packer:

https://github.com/kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons

```
use({
    "kyazdani42/nvim-tree.lua",
    requires = {
        "kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons", -- optional, for file icons
    },
})
```

This is my GitHub repo for this config:

https://github.com/azizgharbi/Neovim-config

Should i install all the icons ? because i only installed one of those icons which is `big blue terminal`.

I am on macOs and using iterm2.

Comment: Yes you should install the font that you want, then set it in the iTerm Profile. 
You can download one of these: https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure to set the terminal font to use the patched font.
To change the font in iTerm2:

1. Start iTerm2.
2. Click iTerm2 → Preferences → Profiles → Text.
3. Choose the patched font on the right.

Comment: Thank you! This is one of those answers buried deep in Stack Overflow to an issue everyone has!

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue when upgraded my distro. Have been using [Nvim-Web-Devicons](https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons) with [lazy.nvim](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim).
The following methods might work for you too:

1. Install a patched version of Nerd Font that supports icon display. [Maybe try some from here that suits you best.](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads)
2. Check if your terminal is set to use the font that you have downloaded in the config.

The config might look similar to this below,

```bash
# Font.
font_family      FiraCode Nerd Font
bold_font        FiraCode Nerd Bold
italic_font      FiraCode Nerd Medium Italic
bold_italic_font FiraCode Nerd Bold Italic
font_size 12
```

3. Actually check if the terminal that you are using supports display of unicode characters if font provided.

If nothing works like mine, then try using the terminal to open the directory that you have installed the plugin for nvim, most probably `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-web-devicons` and run nvim inside that directory and it might trigger some sort of thing that makes it work. Sorry I couldn't provide before and after images for reference and the server won't let me upload either as time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue with my nvim setup on Ubuntu 22.04. @Fady's steps worked great with some extra steps:

- Download one of the latest [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads).
- Install fonts:

  ```bash
  # copy the downloaded `.otf` or `.ttf` files to system fonts directory.
  sudo cp *.otf /usr/share/fonts/

  # after copying fonts, refresh systems font cache by below command
  sudo fc-cache -fv
  ```
- Now, you shoud set teminal font by choosing one of the patched fonts.

After, folllowing these steps icons should be visible to you once you reopen your nvim.