# Neovim lualine and nvim-tree symbols show as weird squares instead of letters

Tags: fonts, neovim, neovim-plugin

Edit: I now understand that for some reason my font does not have support for the glyphs in question, still don't know how to solve it.

I am using the "Lazy" package manager to configure neovim on my ubuntu machine, I have lualine and nvim-tree installed by Lazy, I have installed and am using a patched [nerd font](https://www.nerdfonts.com/) (hack regular) in the terminal.

For some reason both the symbols in the lualine status bar:

[image: see the bottom right]

And in the nvim-tree panel all do not display properly:

[image: see here in top left]

I expected the nvim-tree symbols to be folders and files etc and the lualine symbols to be the language I am using etc. I tried figuring out if this is a font problem or a configuration problem but so far had no luck.

Comment: I don't see any Chinese, only "this font doesn't support the characters it needs to display" [tofu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) boxes. Why did you call that "Chinese"?

Comment: because in the square boxes there some weird characters, looks like letters in some language, it's not really chinese.

Comment: The boxes in your first screenshot contain normal numbers and letters that are on your keyboard right now and that you can read just fine. They're spelling out unicode codepoint number that your font doesn't have support for. I have no idea why there's a `~` in a box in your second screenshot (other than your font clearly not supporting that character either) but that, too, is a normal letter that's on your keyboard right now, not Chinese. I would strongly advise you to not call things you don't recognize "Chinese", just say you don't recognize it.

Comment: I have the same issue I fixed those by following the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78010819/10217732

Answer (score 0):

Download one of the nerd fonts here: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts#patched-fonts

Then change your terminal font to use it.

EDIT: install this as well https://github.com/nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons

Comment: hey, thank you for the answer, as i said in the  question i already have a patched nerd form installed and used (hack)

Comment: Thanks @dragonlobster for the update, before I was using kyazdani42/nvim-web-devicons,unfortunately changing it to nvim-tree/nvim-web-devicons does not make a difference.