# How to change the font of a terminal in a docker container?

Tags: docker, fonts, neovim

I'm installing NvChad in a docker container and I'm installing the Fira Code font. I was able to get this to work on my local machine and it works in a docker container but can't change the font.  I have it in a docker container so I can have the tooling somewhere that's not my local computer which I wouldn't have access/permission to edit terminal settings. I tried to set the guifont in NvChad and edit inside the init.luia file and that did nothing.

```
-- Font settings
vim.cmd([[set guifont=FiraCode\ Nerd\ Font:h12]])
```

The way I'm installing NvChad is very standard
`git clone https://github.com/NvChad/NvChad ~/.config/nvim --depth 1 && nvim`
And I'm installing the font

```
wget https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/releases/download/v3.0.2/FiraCode.zip
mkdir ~/.local/share/fonts
unzip FiraCode.zip -d ~/.local/share/fonts/
fc-cache ~/.local/share/fonts
```

I've looked at these already:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184554/how-to-fix-nvchad-not-displaying-icons#:~:text=This%20is%20because%20the%20font,it%20as%20your%20terminal%20font.&text=Thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184554/how-to-fix-nvchad-not-displaying-icons#:%7E:text=This%20is%20because%20the%20font,it%20as%20your%20terminal%20font.&text=Thanks).
  (I've also tried fira code for font)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/134xy1n/nvchad_not_displaying_icons_or_incorrectly_doing/

It works if I can change the setting of my terminal but in the case I need I won't be able to so I'm looking to see if I can change the font programmatically via a bash script or something. Thanks for any help!

Comment: changing the font usually involve with changing font in the terminal emulator itself, not the font in the vim settings.